# Chatbase seems to censor some words

Tags: chatbase

I just integrated Chatbase with my Dialogflow chatbot via REST API.
So far everything is working, however I noticed that, especially for "Not handled" inputs, some words looks like censored and are replaced by a <*> sequence.

Is that normal? I can't find any reference in the documentation or any way to change this.

If it helps, my chatbot is in Italian and replaced words are not offensive at all. In addition this only happens with some inputs, not all..

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do support for Chatbase, thank you for posting this question!  We automatically mask any sequence of characters that may be considered SPII (sensitive personally identifiable information). Typically, names and string sequences containing consecutive numbers get replaced with the <*> mask.
You can reveal the full message by using the [Transcripts](https://chatbase.com/documentation/transcripts) feature available on the Messages Report.

Regards,
Sean